# Finding the limit of a series using Riemann integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

I am having trouble finding the limit of the series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^p}{n^{p+1}}$$

using Riemann integrals, where $p>1$.

Here's what I have tried so far:

I began by using the integral
$$\int_1^n \frac{x^p}{n^{p+1}} dx = \frac{1}{p+1} - \frac{1}{(p+1)n^{p+1}}$$

This approaches $\frac{1}{p+1}$ as n approaches infinity.

Next, I used Riemann integrals for the tagged partition interval ${{1, ..., n+1}}$ and the partition $Y_i = \frac{i^p}{n^{p+1}}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ to argue that this Riemann integral also approaches $\frac{1}{p+1}$ as n approaches infinity.

However, I am unsure if my argument is correct, as I am having trouble understanding how the delta of ${1, ..., n+1}$ fits the definition. Can someone point out where I went wrong and give me a hint for the solution?

Comment: Hint. The integral should be $\int_0^1 x^p\,dx$. The interval $[0,1]$ is divided into $n$ intervals of length $1/n$ .

Comment: Thank you for the hit! Guess i was way off